# C# Extract part of the string that starts with specific word

Tags: c#

I have multiple strings that looks:

```
this is ab-skdn string
ab-sdhnif my string
```

For each string, I need to pull the part that is ab-**
For example I need ab-skdn and ab-sdhnif

How could I do that using C#

My code would look like something:

```
var myString = "this is ab-skdn string"
match = "ab-skdn"
```

Comment: Is [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-string)) good enough or not?  e.g.: `IndexOf("ab-")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) to find the matches. A simple regex that does what you need is:

```
ab-[a-z]*
```

Since you didn't provide any code I can't provide an example for how to use a regex in your context, but there are plenty of examples out there. A quick google search on how to use Regex in C# should get you started. The link I provided also has some good examples.

Comment: If you need to avoid matching your phrase inside words (like "backst**ab-able**"), you might consider a negative lookbehind for a word boundary: `(?<\b)ab-\w+` or some whitespace: `(?<\s)ab-\w+`.

Comment: On that note, you can learn a lot about how Regexs work and write your own by playing around with a tool such as [this one](https://regex101.com/r/zhQH3f/1)